# How to configure red5 as a server of red5phone?

Tags: voip, red5

I will build a web based voip with red5phone as a client, I get it form here, http://code.google.com/p/red5phone/

but i have no idea how to configure red5 server. I know that red5 have to be coded with java.
Did someone have experiences?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your OS you can either get the source or a precompiled .exe from [here](http://red5.org/downloads/red5/1_0/).

Once you get it built / installed there will be a `webapps` folder. Put your .war files there and start the service. It will unpack the files and make them available.

Looks like your VOIP app has a flex component as well. You'll need to edit the connection params in there to point to your Red5 server. Make sure all the requisite ports are open.